# CONTAINS in Sql Function

Tags: sql-server, contains

I wish to use `CONTAINS` in my function but `CONTAINS(@Ubicacion,TP.Ubicacion)` does not accept my input parameter `@Ubicacion` that is a `varchar`.

What is wrong??

Please can you help me? Thanks

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_BuscaTiempo]
(
   @Destino CHAR(3),
   @Ubicacion NVARCHAR(MAX) 
)
RETURNS TIME
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Tiempo TIME    

    SELECT @Tiempo = TP.Tiempo 
    FROM mar_TiemposArribo TP 
    WHERE TP.Destino = @Destino 
      AND CONTAINS(@Ubicacion, TP.Ubicacion)

    RETURN @Tiempo
END
```

Comment: Do you mean `AND TP.Ubicacion LIKE '%'+ @Ubicacion + '%'` and shouldn't it be `Contains(TP.Ubicacion,@Ubicacion)`

Comment: What does "not acept" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Does this table actually have a full-text catalog defined? [Where is your schema prefix on the table name?](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx) Also, what if more than one row matches the criteria? Do you care which row you get? Currently you don't have any control over that...

Comment: @Ubicacion receives input parameters like '17000 IH-10 West, San Antonio, Texas' and the table 'mar_TiemposArribo TP' TP.Ubicacion have a locations, like 'Colorado,USA', 'San Antonio, Texas' ... i wish find the all directions that include 4 example 'San Antonio, Texas'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose [AD.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693272/ad-net)'s first guess is correct and you just mixed up the parameters of that function in the wrong order. (i.e. you want to search for rows with `@Ubicacion`'s contents inside the column `TP.Ubicacion`)

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx), first parameter shall be a column name or column list and second is the term you search for; applying to your example

```
CONTAINS(TP.Ubicacion, @Ubicacion)
```

Comment: An option to do the otherwise? Search TP.Ubicacion inside @Ubicacion

Comment: @Monse yes there is; [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx#United%20States%20%28English%29) returns the index at which a certain string was found inside a `varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or varbinary(max)` **not zero based**, it returns 0 if the string was not found, 1 if found at first index, ...

Answer (score 0):

> Cause CONTAINS Function doesn't work as I need, I change CONTAINS to
>   LIKE

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_BuscaTiempo]
(
   @Destino CHAR(3),
   @Ubicacion VARCHAR(120)    
)

RETURNS TIME

BEGIN
  DECLARE @Tiempo TIME    
  SELECT @Tiempo=TP.Tiempo FROM mar_TiemposArribo TP WHERE TP.Destino=@Destino AND @Ubicacion **LIKE '%'+ TP.Ubicacion + '%'**     *--CONTAINS(@Ubicacion,TP.Ubicacion)*     
RETURN @Tiempo
END
```

> @Ubicacion receives input parameters like '17000 IH-10 West, San
>   Antonio, Texas' and the table 'mar_TiemposArribo TP' TP.Ubicacion have
>   a locations, like 'Colorado,USA', 'San Antonio, Texas' ... i wish find
>   the all directions that include 4 example 'San Antonio, Texas'